# retrieve data and display in droplist (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

can anyone tell me what is the error  in this dam code i went crazy searching about the error but without any success 
the error is that i do not get any data from the table why is that happening?? plz help me

## index.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<label for="searchByCountry">By Country</label>
            <select name="searchByCountry" id="searchByCountry">
             <option id="0">--select your country--</option>
             <?php
                 require_once('connfor_lamelchameltest.php'); 



               $getallCountries = mysql_query("SELECT country_name FROM country") or die("could not search for countries");
         if(mysql_num_rows($getallCountries) > 0) {

               while($viewallCountries = mysql_fetch_array($getallCountries)){

                ?>

               <option id="<?php echo $viewallCountries['country_name']; ?> "></option>
                 <?php } ?>
               <?php } ?>

            </select>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: What have you tried already? Also, what is in your database? How are you calling it? What is inside `connfor_lamelchameltest.php`? Work on this question.

Comment: i tried to call or retrieve data from the table country that contain country_id and country_name  the connection is made by the **connfor_lamelchameltest.php** that handle the configuration and the connection

Comment: 1. check if mysql_num_rows returns 0. if not
2. check if $viewallCountiers['country_name'] is empty
3. your <option> tag is empty, you only set the id, do:
`<option id="<?php echo $viewallCountries['country_name'];?>"><?php echo $viewallCountries['country_name'];?></option>`
4. you should set `<option value="">..` or there wont be anything posted if you submit the form.
5. learn to use firebug / chrome debug tools or something similar
6. use the php functions echo/var_dump/print_r to make debug output

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<label for="searchByCountry">By Country</label>
            <select name="searchByCountry" id="searchByCountry">
             <option id="0">--select your country--</option>
             <?php
                 require_once('connfor_lamelchameltest.php'); 



               $getallCountries = mysql_query("SELECT country_name FROM country") or die("could not search for countries");
         if(mysql_num_rows($getallCountries) > 0) {

               while($viewallCountries = mysql_fetch_array($getallCountries)){

                ?>

               <option value="<?php echo $viewallCountries['country_name']; ?> ">
<?php echo $viewallCountries['country_name']; ?>
</option>
                 <?php } ?>
               <?php } ?>

            </select>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: still do not have anything display why is that happening i do not understand what is the error or the mistake that i wrote in my code

Comment: That might be because mysql_num_rows returns 0. I would suggest you not using mysql functions as they are deprecated and would be removed soon. Instead use mysqli or pdo.